# How to pass json object as a parameter to another powershell script

Tags: json, powershell

I am quite new to powershell stuff. So need some help here.

I want to pass a json object as a parameter to another ps1. From what I read after searching is that I need to convert it to powershell object from json string. Please correct me if I am wrong. This is what I am doing

Calling script:

```
$jsonParams = "{
     `"TaskName`": `"$taskName`",
      `"ExitCode`": `"$exitCode`",
      `"ErrorMessage`": `"$errorMessage`"
   }

$jsonObject = $jsonParams | ConvertFrom-Json
$argumentList = @($param1, $param2, $jsonObject) 

Invoke-Expression "& `"$scriptPath`" $argumentList"
```

and in called script -

```
param (
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2,
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.JsonObject]$jsonObject
)
```

But, the calling script throws error

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (21): {
```

What's wrong with this code. Also, after json object is passed to called script, how should I access its values in it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Your JSON is malformed. I think the core issue is that you have a trailing comma at the end of your JSON. You also don't close the opening quotation in your declaration.

You might have a much easier time if you use a here-string for this anyway. This was you don't have to use all those backticks.

```
$jsonParams = @"
{
     "TaskName": "$taskName",
      "ExitCode": "$exitCode",
      "ErrorMessage": "$errorMessage"
   }
"@

$jsonObject = $jsonParams | ConvertFrom-Json
```

---

`$jsonObject` is already a custom object and no longer JSON. You don't need to do anything special with it. Remove the type in your param block and just call the properties in your script.

```
param (
    [string]$param1,
    [string]$param2,
    $jsonObject
)
$jsonObject.TaskName
```

Comment: This is only a partial answer as you will still get an error with that type cast. I don't use that so I am not sure what the issue is there other than the text is no longer JSON as you converted it.

Comment: That was just typo while putting the question, Actually there are more parameters in my code. So I copy-pasted few of them. Also, the quotes are properly closed too. As shown in your code, I added the here-string header but same is the error again :(

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you are passing to the variables that make the json? You could print the herestring or your string into http://jsonlint.com/ to see where the issue is with it. You have a syntax error that you are hiding I feel now.

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad. There was some problem while reading the ini file values which were forming my json string. I fixed that and checked on the above link and it showed me it is valid json. Also, that error is gone now but if I try to access json values in destination file with your code, it prints nothing.

Comment: Fyi.. `@{TaskName=setup; ExitCode=1; ErrorMessage=NoError;}` This is the output after `ConvertFrom-Json` is executed