# Pass adminPassword Parameter from JSON template to PS script Switch

Tags: json, azure, powershell, active-directory, safe-mode

I'm building a JSON template that deploys a VM in Azure and executing a PowerShell script via Custom Script Extension (CSE). The JSON template was taken from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-vm-simple-windows) with some modifications for my company needs.

One of the parameters in the JSON template is `adminPassword`, that configures the password for the VM's local admin account.

The PowerShell script should deploy a domain controller on the VM. This is the important part of the PS script:

```
Install-ADDSForest -CreateDnsDelegation:$false -DatabasePath C:\Windows\NTDS -DomainMode 7 -DomainName Domain.local -DomainNetbiosName Domain -ForestMode 7 -InstallDns:$true -LogPath C:\Windows\NTDS -SysvolPath C:\Windows\SYSVOL -NoRebootOnCompletion:$false -Force:$true
```

The `Install-ADDSForest` command requires the switch `-SafeModeAdministratorPassword` for the command to run.
Adding the password as plain text at the beginning of the PS script works, **but plain text password is not an option**. This is how I tested:

```
$SafePassPlain = 'Password'
$SafePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -string $SafePassPlain `
    -AsPlainText -force
```

And entering this in the `Install-ADDSForest` line: `-SafeModeAdministratorPassword $SafePass`

This is the part in the JSON template where the script runs:

```
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
        "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "1.4",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        "settings": {
          "fileUris": [
            "https://URLtoFile/DC-Domain.ps1
          ],
          "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File DC-Domain.ps1"
```

**I would like to pass the adminPassword parameter from the JSON template to the PS script so it will use it for the `-SafeModeAdministratorPassword` switch.
Is it possible?**

I read about `ConvertFrom-Json` and checked these: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34165334/how-to-pass-json-object-as-a-parameter-to-another-powershell-script) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53490414/how-to-pass-json-string-data-to-powershell), but I'm not sure how to implement that on my end...

After checking [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-core-sample-templates/blob/master/dotnet-core-music-windows/azuredeploy.json) and [this](http://harvestingclouds.com/post/step-by-step-arm-templates-providing-powershell-scripts-to-run-after-vm-deployment-via-arm-template/), seeing examples of passing parameters from a JSON template to a PS script, I tried implementing it like this, which didn't work:

```
"commandToExecute": "[concat('powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File DC-Domain1.ps1 -SafeModeAdministratorPassword ',parameters('adminPassword'))]"
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Could you provide the error in your question?

Comment: The custom script execution just keeps running for about an hour and times out (I guess waiting for the -SafeModeAdministratorPassword). The log under `C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Compute.CustomScriptExtension` doesn't show any errors...
If needed, I will redeploy the VMs and give more details. 
I guess that the real question is if passing a parameter from the JSON template to a PS script the template runs is even possible/supported and how should it be written in the template > commandToEexecute and in the PS script.